# iOS popup menu (android toolbar menu analog)

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu, popupmenu

I'm new to iOS. And I'm trying to get popup menu as I did on Android:
[image]
[image]

This menu should disappear when the user clicks on another area of the screen.
I found the same menu in the YouTube app for iOS, but I didn't find a simple solution for that. I tried using popup window with "Present Modally" segue, but it behaves differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) to quickly add a dropdown menu. Can read more: https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown